# iOS Objective C Authorisation issue when Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: objective-c, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-tasks-api

I am currently working with Google API with Objective C and OAuth 2.0 api is giving me a headache whole day

I have been looking at [google's documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction)

And I have managed to get to a stage where I can login and 'Allow Access'

The issue arises the following step.

From API, I get Authentication Token.  and according to the documentation I'm following ( link above)

I can authorise the request with method

```
[auth authorizeRequest:myNSURLMutableRequest
          delegate:self
 didFinishSelector:@selector(authentication:request:finishedWithError:)];
```

then I have no idea what 'myNSURLMutableRequest' is.

Any advice so much appreciated

By the way I am going to work with Google Task API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a existing library to use a service with OAuth protocol. You don't have to reinvent the wheel !

https://github.com/leebyron/cocoa-oauth2

https://github.com/lukeredpath/LROAuth2Client

Comment: Thanks!! but any idea what the request would be?

Comment: I've never use OAuth 2.0. Only the 1.0. I don't want to tell you something wrong.

You can take a look at Google documentation :

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to setback your saved auth object from keychain

GTMOAuth2Authentication *authObj;
 authObj = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                 clientID:GoogleClientID
                                                             clientSecret:GoogleClientSecret];

BOOL isSignedIn = [authObj canAuthorize];